# When there is a failure in ASSERT_ macro of gtest, the TearDown function will be called or not?

Tags: assert, googletest

Will the TearDown function be called when the ASSERT_EQ fails in google test? Or it just cancel that test case and move to the next one without TearDown? This is because in my TearDown function, I need to do something to properly shutdown the test function, so I'm afraid that this ASSERT will make my test not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not hard to satisfy yourself that `TearDown` is always run, regardless
of whether an `ASSERT_...` macro fails:

**testcase.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct foo : ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp()
    {
        std::cout << ">>>" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " was run " << std::endl;
    }

    void TearDown()
    {
        std::cout << ">>>" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " was run " << std::endl;
    }
};

TEST_F(foo,bar)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(1,0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile and link:

```
g++ -o testcase testcase.cpp -lgtest -pthread
```

Run:

```
$ ./testcase
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from foo
[ RUN      ] foo.bar
>>>virtual void foo::SetUp() was run 
testcase.cpp:19: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  1
  0
>>>virtual void foo::TearDown() was run 
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from foo (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] foo.bar

 1 FAILED TEST
```